# Extend struct in inheriting class

Tags: c++, inheritance, directx

Is it possible to declare a struct in a parent class and define it in the inheriting child class (in every child class it should look different)?

An example would look like this:

```
class parent
{
    virtual struct AlwaysDifferentStructure;

    //Some methods here
    //...
};

class child1 : public parent
{
    struct AlwaysDifferentStructure
    {
        int foo;
    }

    //Some methods here
    //...
};

class child2 : public parent
{
    struct AlwaysDifferentStructure
    {
        char* foo;
        float bar;
        double foobar;
    }

    //Some methods here
    //...
};
```

So actually what I am trying do deal with is the following:
I got a parent class `shader` and a lot of inheriting classes (i.e. `simple_color_shader`). Each shader has its own vertex structure. Now I want to render an object with one of these shader but I don't know how the vertex struct exactly looks like because it is always different but I need it. So I thought that I could just redeclare the struct in all the children and gain access through the parent. So in the `object` class it basically looks like this:

```
class object
{
    parent* m_pParent;
    AlwaysDifferentStructure* m_structArray;
};
```

(Just ask if you don't understand what I'm trying to tell you; my english is not that good)

My question is: Is this even possible and if yes i would appreciate if someone could tell me how.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you had such a facility, what would you use it for? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you clarify the "gain access through the parent" part? What is the code that uses `AlwaysDifferentStructure` is supposed to look like? The example you show would happily compile once you drop the nonsensical `virtual struct AlwaysDifferentStructure;` line. If you'd like further help, you need to show the actual usage you have difficulty with.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik gain access would mean that I create the array with `new` and it is then the `struct` from the children the pointer `m_pParent` is pointing to

Comment: How would you use this pointer, when you don't know what members the structures it points to have? How would it be different from plain old `void*`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh yes you are right that is absolut nonsense because I don't know what members the struct has. Sry for being such an idiot. Gonna think about other solutions :D

Comment: Is [this](https://godbolt.org/g/bip8ne) what you are looking for?

Comment: Or [this](https://godbolt.org/g/IHF8cu)?

Comment: I think the second (the templates) are pretty good. thx,

Answer (score 0):

something like this can be accomplished with the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
template <typename derived>
class parent
{
    void someMethod ()
    {
        typename derived::AlwaysDifferentStructure x;

        x.foo;
    }
};

class child1 : public parent <child1>
{
    struct AlwaysDifferentStructure
    {
        int foo;
    }

    //Some methods here
    //...
}

class child2 : public parent <child2>
{
    struct AlwaysDifferentStructure
    {
        char* foo;
        float bar;
        double foobar;
    }

    //Some methods here
    //...
}
```

Comment: but if i wouldn't have a `foo` in `child2` then `someMethod` would fail, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Rafiwui Yes. I assume that each different version of the structure has something in common. In your example foo was it.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>For the OP found the snippets posted in the comments to be good suggestions, I'm posting them here for future readers.</sub>

---

Here is a possible approach, as mentioned in the comments:

```
class parent { };
class child1 : public parent { };
class child2 : public parent { };

template<typename>
struct AlwaysDifferentStructure;

template<>
struct AlwaysDifferentStructure<child1> {
    int foo;
};

template<>
struct AlwaysDifferentStructure<child2> {
    char* foo;
    float bar;
    double foobar;
};

int main() {
    AlwaysDifferentStructure<child1> c1t;
    c1t.foo = 42;
    AlwaysDifferentStructure<child2> c2t;
    c2t.foo = new char{'c'};
    c2t.bar = .42;
    c2t.foobar = 0.;
}
```

As another viable solution, you can do this:

```
class parent {
    //Some methods here
    //...
};

class child1 : public parent {
public:
    auto alwaysDifferentStructure() {
        struct S {
            int foo;
        } s;

        return s;
    }
};

class child2 : public parent {
public:
    auto alwaysDifferentStructure() {
        struct S { 
            char* foo;
            float bar;
            double foobar;
        } s;

        return s;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto c1t = child1{}.alwaysDifferentStructure();
    c1t.foo = 42;
    auto c2t = child2{}.alwaysDifferentStructure();
    c2t.foo = new char{'c'};
    c2t.bar = .42;
    c2t.foobar = 0.;
}
```

Note that this second example requires C++14.